# Java annotations throws NullPointerException.

Tags: java, annotations

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. My objective is to get the annotation of a method (if exists).

```
public class RunTest
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, NoSuchMethodException
{
    MyAction action = new MyAction(); 

    Method method = action.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("printSomething");

    RequiredPermission permission = method.getAnnotation(RequiredPermission.class);
    String value = permission.permissionName();

    System.out.println("permission name: "+value);

}
}
```

MyAction class

```
public class MyAction
{
@RequiredPermission(permissionName="SYSO", permissionValue = 0)
public void printSomething()
{
    System.out.println("hi there");
}

public void printABC()
{
    System.out.println("ABC...");
}
}
```

and the annotation:

```
public @interface RequiredPermission
{
    String permissionName();
    int permissionValue();
}
```

I would expect to see on the console:

> permission name: SYSO

but instead I get:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at com.annotation.RunTest.main(RunTest.java:14)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The annotation must have its Retention Policy set to `RUNTIME` in order to access it via reflection.

Add the following to your annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface RequiredPermission
{
    String permissionName();
    int permissionValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably forgot to specify RUNTIME as the [RetentionPolicy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) of your annotation.